# QDataStream: Overloading >> for decorated QVector

Tags: c++, qt, stream, operator-overloading

I have a class `MyVector : QVector<int>`, for which I have an ID and a `QVector` of tags attached to it. When overloading `operator>>` for streaming from a `QDataStream`, I can simply chain the already-defined `operator>>`-functions for the ID and the tag vector. But how do I access the vector data itself for streaming? I cannot simply use `istream >> myVector`, because that's what I'm about to define, giving endless recursion. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast back your instance to the original QVector superclass in order to call the correct >> operator implementation.

```
istream >> static_cast<QVector<int>>(myVector)
```